# cannot access settings.bundle xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was working in xcode 3.2 until yesterday when I made the switch to xcode 4 (yuck to say the least). Anyway in my app within xcode 3.2 I had a section within settings for where the user can choose default states as well as see the current version of the app.

When I run my app in xcode 4, everything works like it did in xcode 3. However; I have just updated my app version and want to change this within the appropriate field within settings but I have no idea how to access this in xcode 4. All I see is a settings.bundle file but when I double click nothing comes up and single click doesn't give me any useful options either.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select settings.bundle, you should be able to expand it as though it was a folder and find a Root.plist file that you can update with your desired settings:

This thread should help you out: [Empty Settings Bundle in Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162846/empty-settings-bundle-in-xcode-4-2)

Comment: Perfect, fixed the problem. Thank you Jose!