# How can I change the UI in my iphone settings at application level

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Basically I want to change the Display of UI that is currently looking as this.
[image]

Now, 
1> In my application i'm just displaying two fields **Username** and **Password** and **I want to remove Role** and **Role_name** fields from the iphone settings as this values are inserted automatically through web service for the user according to user's email address.
2> How can I add **version** and **push notification** options in setting?
Please help me with this need this info badly.
I'm using xcode **version 4.2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, you're using a settings bundle, aren't you?
I've never used settings bundles before but if so, you can remove Role and Role_name fields by deleting its entries int the plist file of the settings bundle.
Then you can add a new entry for the Version. To get it I always use

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]
```

but I'm not sure if this can be used with settings bundle. Finally, for push notifications, their settings are automatically managed by Settings -> Notifications so you don't have to worry about them in your settings bundle.
I hope this can help you but I believe there are other people who know these topics better than me ;)

Comment: Thanks Mate. Yes, I'm using settings bundle However, I couldn't find the role and role_name fields in the plist. Moreover, on clicking the Settings.bundle file its giving me empty editor. Can you please tell me precisely where can I find those files and how?

Comment: it Worked for me man. Actually I was not able to find the two files of my Settings.bundle once I found them and followed your instruction it worked. Found through this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162846/empty-settings-bundle-in-xcode-4-2].